# Kohana - installation issues

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

I am a Kohana newbie who is currently stuck with the installation process. 
I have downloaded the latest version(3.3.1) of kohana and installed it in my php server. The kohana installation asked to me to delete the install.php as it found that  my server is well equipped to run kohana based applications.

I have renamed the install.php. and used the following url to get kohana homepage.  `www.mydomain.com/kohana`, kohana is where i uploaded the kohana files.

When i tried running above URL it ended up an error asking to me to add `Cookie::$Salt` statement to the bootstrap.php. I addded the line `Cookie::$Salt ="foobar"` somewhere below Line 90 of bootstrap.php. Now i am getting the following error.

> Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: `Cookie::$Salt` on
>   line 91

Kindly advice how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static properties are **case sensitive** in PHP! You need to set `$salt`, not `$Salt`.

```
Cookie::$salt = "...";
```